# how to display value of column from another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

How do I display the value of column `Department` from `tblDepartment` to `tblEmployee` in a webform table? I have this code but it only displays the `DeptID`.

This is the Page_load code

```
        sConn = new SqlConnection(sStr);
        daEmp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", sConn);
        daDep = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblDepartment", sConn);
        dsEmp = new DataSet();
        dsDep = new DataSet();

        daEmp.Fill(dsEmp, "tblEmployee");
        daDep.Fill(dsDep, "tblDepartment");

        dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Columns["EmployeeID"] };

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dgvEmployee.DataSource = dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"];
        dgvEmployee.DataBind();
```

These are the tables

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to display information from two or more different `tables` you can `join` them based on relationship(`primary key` and `foreign key`) columns:

You need to Replace this Query:

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmployee
```

With this:

```
SELECT employee.*,department.Department 
FROM tblEmployee employee 
    INNER JOIN tblDepartment department ON employee.DeptID=department.DeptID
```